# Wierd struct initialisation scope issue?

Tags: c, struct, scope

I'm having an issue with a function I wrote to initialise a struct member.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define START_COL 2
#define MID_COL 30

typedef struct{
    int datsize;
    int selsize;
    char** data;
    uint8_t** seldata;
}Screen;

static const char* HOME_SCREEN[7]={"Ruthless RFID","1.READ CARD","2.WRITE CARD","3.SHOW FILES","4.DISP","5.STATS","6.EXIT"};
static const uint8_t HOME_SEL[6][3]={{2,START_COL,2},{4,START_COL,2},{6,START_COL,2},{2,MID_COL+15,2},{4,MID_COL+15,2},{6,MID_COL+15,2}};

void SCREEN_INIT(Screen* screen){

    screen->datsize=7;
    screen->selsize=6;
    screen->data=(char**)malloc((screen->datsize));
    screen->seldata=(uint8_t**)malloc(screen->selsize*sizeof(uint8_t**));

    for(int i=0;i<screen->selsize;i++){
        screen->seldata[i]=(uint8_t*)malloc(3*sizeof(uint8_t));
        memcpy(screen->seldata[i],HOME_SEL[i],3);
        
    }
    memcpy(screen->data,HOME_SCREEN,sizeof(HOME_SCREEN));
}


int main(){
    Screen HOME;
    
    SCREEN_INIT(&HOME);
    printf("%i\n",HOME.seldata[0][0]);
}
```

Essentially I'm initializing the `HOME` member with `HOME_SCREEN[7]` for it's data attribute and `HOME_SEL[6][3]` for it's `seldata` attribute. When I check the `HOME.data` within `main()` it's all as expected. However, when I try to print HOME.seldata[0][0] I get 52 instead of 2 which is what it should be. However, this:

```
int main(){
    Screen HOME;
    
    SCREEN_INIT(&HOME);

    printf("%i\n",HOME.seldata[3][0]);
}
```

Returns the correct value of 2 (first element of 4th array of HOME_SEL). In fact the last three arrays of HOME.seldata are all correct, it's only the first three that are not working. But when I try printing `HOME.seldata[0][0]` from within the `SCREEN_INIT()` function I get the correct value 2. So does this mean there's a scope issue for the first three arrays of `HOME.seldata`? How can this be if the last three arrays are correct?

Comment: Your malloc size for  screen->seldata appears to be incorrect. Your malloc for  screen->data as well.

Comment: OT: don't use all caps identifiers like `SCREEN_INIT`. Those are usually used for macros. This is a convention used by 99.9% of all C programmers.

Comment: @Avi Berger how so? HOME.data has the correct strings in it? I agree the malloc for screen->seldata may be wrong which is causing my issue but I don't know how? Can you elaborate please

Comment: It appears to me that you want screen->data to point to an array of 7 char *'s, but are allocating only 7 bytes. The size should probably be ( screen->datsize * sizeof(char *) ) However you are then copying in to it the values of **const** char *'s , which is a bad idea. (you are not making copies of the actual strings.)

Comment: Ok thanks. Changing it to screen->datsize * sizeof(char*) seems to have fixed it. Is there a safer way to copy the contents of HOME_SCREEN to screen->data?

Comment: The issue is that you are copying the pointers, not the strings themselves; you are losing the const qualification on the pointers; and the strings are string literals, thus formally not modifiable. Should additional code attempt to modify the const strings via the non-const pointers, the compiler wont notice or warn you, but it would be fair game for bad stuff to happen at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bugs:

- `screen->data=(char**)malloc((screen->datsize));` This won't work. It doesn't make sense to assign a pointer-to-pointer to an arbitrary sized chunk of bytes. You probably meant `malloc(screen->datsize * sizeof(char*)`.
- `malloc(screen->selsize*sizeof(uint8_t**));` This is just wrong, should be `uint8_t*`.

You could also check out [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) as well as the term *flexible array members* for some tips of how to implement this differently. Also ask yourself if you truly need completely variable dimensions in run-time or if this could be simplified - perhaps you don't need dynamic allocation to begin with.